# flatpak commands does not run on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, repository, flatpak

When I try to install Gradio v7.1 via Flatpak, I get this error:

```
error: While opening repository /var/lib/flatpak/repo: opendir(objects): No such file or directory
```

Although I've installed Flatpak via its repo, even other commands give this error:

```
$ flatpak update -v
error: While opening repository /var/lib/flatpak/repo: opendir(objects): No such file or directory
```

Edit: test on Ubuntu 18.04

I already followed the Ubuntu quick setup guide. It installs flatpak package but commands does not run on Ubuntu 16.04. I've already tested on Ubuntu 18.04. No problems occured. Gradio can be installed via flatpak without any problems.

I try to find the problem for 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the missing objects directory in `/var/lib/flatpak/repo` .

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/flatpak/repo/objects/
```

Gradio can be installed by the following commands in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak # required in 16.04 only, not in later releases
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub de.haeckerfelix.gradio
```

The first command to add ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak is not required in 18.04 and later because the flatpak package is in the default repositories.

Gradio can be launched by clicking on its icon in the Dash or launched from the terminal with the following command:

```
flatpak run de.haeckerfelix.gradio
```

Comment: As you can see any "flatpak" commands returns error. I already followed the Ubuntu quick setup guide. It installs flatpak package but commands does not run on Ubuntu 16.04. I've already tested on Ubuntu 18.04. No problems.

Comment: Thanks for help. Although there was not any warning that the "objects" directory was missing. But runnning this command solve the issue.

Comment: Better is to allow recreate whole directory tree by `rm -rf /var/lib/flatpak/repo` and then do `flatpak remote-add ...` again.